# What does the phrase "50% premium" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the context of commissioning a piece of artistic work, what does the phrase "50% premium" mean?

Sentence for context:

> Would a 50% premium be OK to include a transfer of IP rights for said art piece?

Comment: My guess would be that they are offering half the purchase price for the right to the Intellectual Property.  So if the painting asking price was $200.  They would be offering $300 to buy the painting plus the rights to the IP.

Comment: @Jim, that's what I was thinking but I wasn't exactly sure. But seeing as I'm not alone in my thoughts I'll either delete this or if you post it as an answer, accept it.

Comment: Jim's comment plus a citation would make a good answer.

Comment: @ardentsonata Why would you delete it?  The whole point of Stack Exchange is to accumulate questions and answers that will be useful to lots more people in the future.  Deleting your question just because you've already received a satisfactory answer seems selfish to me.

Comment: You have found a satisfactory and reasonably authentic answer, you can post it yourself as well.

Comment: In the context of a contact, this is just ambiguous enough to be dangerous, and you likely should ask for clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the price is increased by half the original asking price. If the asking price without IP rights is $100, the price with the rights is:

```
$100 + ($100 * 50%) = $150.
```